# How to call a brush's on function

Tags: d3.js

In [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/vNaR-vJ9hMg/ztLDbTD-_hMJ), Mike Bostock explains that setting a brush's extent and redrawing the brush are two separate operations. I understand this, but I'm having trouble working out the details.

He says you need to do something like the following:

```
brush.extent([0.2, 0.8]); 
svg.select(".brush").call(brush);
```

However, when I execute `call(brush)`, it simply draws the brush rectangle on the new extent. The 'focus' chart never gets updated. However, if I call my `brushed` function (the function that I assigned to my brush), it works.

It seems like `call(brush)` doesn't execute `brushed`. How do I get it to execute this function?

UPDATE: [Here's a fiddle with my code](http://jsfiddle.net/samselikoff/rbxQq/1/). When you run it, notice the brush is correctly drawn, but the focus is not updated. Uncomment line 180, and the focus gets redrawn too.

(Of course, eventually I will want to do this from outside the chart object, but for now I am doing it within just to try to figure out what's going wrong.)

Essentially, I'm asking: **How can I trigger the `brushed` function from outside the object?** How does the brush event handler do it?

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `extent` of a brush explicitly doesn't trigger the event that causes the function associated with it to be called. In this case the simplest solution is to, as you already found out, call `brushed()` explicitly after setting the extent.

Comment: But wouldn't it return an error, or at least not draw the rectangle? Perhaps you could look at my code - I've posted a fiddle.

Comment: Ah ok, I see your point now. In this case you do actually need to call `brushed` explicitly because just setting the extent doesn't trigger the event that will cause `brushed` to be called automatically. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I know setting the `extent` doesn't trigger `brushed`, but isn't `.call(brush)` supposed to? If not, how do I call the `brushed` function from outside the chart object?

Comment: No, `.call(brush)` does exactly that -- call `brush` and not trigger any events. If you want to call `brushed` from outside the chart object, either expose it from the chart object or declare it outside.

Comment: Hmm.. but Mike's advice seems to suggest that calling `brush` is in fact how you redraw after setting the extent. In any case, do you have any suggestions on how to expose it? I'm having trouble, since it's part of the inner `chart` function (rather than a method of the outer TimeSeriesChart object).

Comment: In fact the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-_brush) makes it sound like calling `.on(brush)` should redraw the chart.

Comment: I've got a solution. I still feel like `brush()` is supposed to trigger the `brushed` event, though.

Comment: You could file a bug/feature request for that.